# Embeddable HTML/CSS/script engine C++

Tags: html, c++, css, twitter-bootstrap, sciter

I have a C++ Windows native application and I would like to have a HTML engine to display data in the GUI.
I found [Sciter](https://sciter.com/) perfect for this, but it has a not complete css/js support: for example loading [bootstrap 4](http://getbootstrap.com/) starting template make the app crashing; version 2 loads, but it does not render properly, because of a lot of css loading errors.
Is there any [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) porting available for Sciter (or some similar alternatives)?

Answer (score 1):

Sciter doesn't support most of **current css properties**, it only supports a hand full of **css3**, You've got to find another way of coming up with a bootstrap layout.

Comment: No browser supports all of CSS3.  Sciter supports more-or-less all CSS you will ever need, even if the syntax isn't identical.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Chromium Embedded Framework](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef). Which is basically a embedded Chrome.